# Discover tests in sub-package

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a package with several hundred tests organized in modules, and I'm in the process of moving some of those tests into their own sub-package for ease of maintenance. My question is how to organize the files so Python's std `unittest` module can discover *and* isolate them if I only want to execute some of the test.

The current directory layout goes something like the following:

```
/my_project/[...]

/test/__init__.py
/test/test_missiles.py
/test/test_launch_procedure.py

/test/fallback/__init__.py
/test/fallback/test_sticks.py
/test/fallback/test_stones.py
```

I can have `unittest` discover and execute the `fallback` tests individually by means of

```bash
python3 -m unittest test.fallback.test_sticks
```

yet what I want to do is execute all `fallback`-related tests in one go. However, `unittest` does not discover the modules inside the sub-package; e.g.

```bash
python3 -m unittest test.fallback
```

... will execute no tests at all.

Using filenames instead of paths also works, yet only for single files; e.g. `-m unittest test/fallback/test_sticks.py` works for a single module, but not for to-be-expanded patterns like `test/fallback/test_s*.py`.

Do I need the `fallback`-test-subpackage to somehow assist with test-discovery, so a normal `python3 -m unittest test.fallback` would load and execute all tests from that package?

Comment: Not exactly what you're asking, but if you can consider [pytest](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.4.x/) instead of the builtin unittest, it might work better for you (and definitely supports that scenario: `py.test test/fallback`)

Comment: @akx, duly noted, but if possible I'd prefer to stick with stdlib